# Ubuntu 12.10 - launcher stays hidden

Tags: launcher, display, 12.10

Just upgraded to 12.10 today. Everything seems fine for now, aprat from one thing:

The launcher on the left side of the screen doesn't come up after moving the cursor to the left side of the screen. It IS there since it show the app start animation and I can have it on top all the time, but I'm really fond of it being hidden most of the time.

I did check the sensitivity settings and even set it up to MAX (thus high) and it changes nothing.

Please help ;)
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the sollution! At least this solves the problem if you have NVIDIA hardware (Geforce Go 7300):

In your Sofware Updater program go to "Settings" -> "Additional Software". There select the bottom radion button: "Using experimental NVIDIA...".

This installs the latest NVIDIA driver for your hardware. Now reboot your computer and you should be good to go!

Comment: Suprisingly enough - it does work :) Thanks JePe!

Comment: Confirmed, fixed the issue for me as well, card is a GF119/Quadro NVS 4200M.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem. Here's some additional information of my own research so far:

My hardware details: Lenovo 3000 n200 (with NVIDIA Geforce Go 7300)
In the past (around February 2012) some similar problems existed in combination with NVIDIA gfx hardware. See Launchpad.

Solutions with adjusting settings in CompizConfig Settings Manager didn't solve the problem. And of course as Mieszko stated higher the sensitivity settings in System Settings -> Appearance didn't help as well.